# How to check command status while redirect standard error output to a file?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script having the following command

```
rm ${thefile}
```

In order to ensure the command is execute successfully, I use `$?` variable to check on the status, but this variable doesn't show the exact error? To do this, I redirect the standard error output to a log file using following command:

```
rm ${file} >> ${LOG_FILE} 2>&1
```

With this command I can't use `$?` variable to check status on the `rm` command because the command behind the `rm` command is executed successfully, thus `$?` variable is kind of useless here.

May I know is there a solution that could combine both features where I'm able to check on the status of `rm` command and at mean time I'm allow to redirect the output?

Comment: " because the command behind the rm command is executed successfully" Please explain what you mean by this. $? will still return a value > 0 if rm failed.

Comment: What you have looks correct to me. Tested on my desktop too.

Comment: The assertion that _'with this command I can't use `$?` variable to check status on the `rm` command'_ is incorrect.  The exit status of the command is independent of where the I/O redirection sends standard output and standard error (except that if the I/O redirections fail, the command is not executed at all).  Given the false premise, it is not surprising that your conclusion _'thus $? variable is kind of useless here'_ is incorrect.  You can use `if rm ${file} >> ${LOG_FILE} 2>&1; then : OK; else : Failed; fi` as just one of many ways of testing the status of the `rm` command.

Comment: Deepest regret posting this question while I was running some issues at production site. I was kind of mess just now and I didn't pay much attention on my verification. Thousand apologies on this mistake.

Answer (score 6):

> With this command I can't use `$?` variable to check status on the `rm` command because the command behind the `rm` command is executed successfully, thus `$?` variable is kind of useless here.

That is simply not true. All of the redirections are part of a single command, and `$?` contains its exit status.

What you may be thinking of is cases where you have multiple commands arranged in a pipeline:

```
command-1 | command-2
```

When you do that, `$?` is set to the exit status of the *last* command in the pipeline (in this case `command-2`), and you need to use the `PIPESTATUS` array to get the exit status of other commands. (In this example `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` is the exit status of `command-1` and `${PIPESTATUS[1]}` is equivalent to `$?`.)

Comment: While helpful, examining the elements of `${PIPESTATUS[@]}` for any failure in a pipeline is somewhat cumbersome (cf. the `pipefail` option). Here's a shortcut: `if (( ${PIPESTATUS[@]/%/ +} + 0 > 0 )); then echo "At least 1 command failed."; fi`
`

Comment: @mklement0: If you are looking for the exit-status of a specific command in a pipeline, `PIPESTATUS` is the best way to do that. (Partly because it's the only way to do that, and partly because it's a perfectly fine way to that.) I agree that it's not ideal if your goal is to determine if *any* command in a pipeline has failed, but this is veering increasingly far from the OP's actual question . . .

Comment: Point taken - and agreed - but since _you_ brought up pipelines and `PIPESTATUS` and the OP's question is about failure _in the abstract_ (no mention of multiple commands or pipelines), I thought I'd mention it. In light of _you_ leading us down the yellow-pipe road, I suggest not punishing @konsolebox for it, though - commenting on how it's a tangent is fine, but the answer still has value.

Comment: @mklement0: I don't believe that konsolebox's answer has value on this page. I think it's fine for an answer to *go* on a tangent, if the answerer thinks that will be helpful; for example, konsolebox's answer could have value as *part* of an answer that either (1) answered the question or (2) explained why the question is ill-founded. But I don't think it's O.K. for an answer to *start* on a tangent, whereby it never has anything to do with the question.

Comment: @mklement0: (Even so, I wouldn't have downvoted if it weren't for his/her blatantly-false first sentence. The OP has an actual problem, or thinks (s)he does, and konsolebox's answer offers a putative solution *that actually has nothing to do with that problem*.)

Comment: Point taken re distinction between answering and _adding_ a tangent vs. _answering with_ a tangent. @konsolebox's answer actually improves on _your tangent_, not the original question :) As such it is more of an answer to _your answer_. Whatever the outcome, at least our comments now cover the thinking behind the voting.

Comment: No need to take it seriously guys :) With or with ruakh's solution, and also a veteran bash script contributer here who's been on a hiatus and just having fun today, I thnk the solution would have been made with or without ruakh's answer for it's a long known solution already at least since last year. Besides, the comments directly made under his question would have been the solution for it already and I just made an assumption about his description `because the command behind the rm command is executed successfully`. Old folks don't struggle with common minor stuffs. You don't prove anything.

Comment: @konsolebox Excellent point re `because the command behind the rm command is executed successfully` - I missed that. I suggest you add it and your inference as a preamble to your answer (not just for your own vindication, but for the benefit of future readers too).

Answer (score 1):

What you probably need is the shell option `pipefail` in bash (from `man bash`):

> The return status of a pipeline is the exit status of the last command, unless
>   the pipefail option is enabled.  If pipefail is enabled, the pipeline's return
>   status is the value of the last (rightmost) command to exit with a non-zero sta‐
>   tus, or zero if all commands exit successfully.  If the reserved word !  precedes
>   a pipeline, the exit status of that pipeline is the logical negation of the exit
>   status as described above.  The shell waits for all commands in the pipeline to
>   terminate before returning a value.

```bsh
> shopt -s -o pipefail
> true | false
> echo $?
1
> false | true
> echo $?
1
true | true
echo $?
0
```

Comment: +1; the advantage of `shopt -so pipefail` over using `${PIPESTATUS[@]}` is that you don't need to search through the elements of the latter to find a nonzero exit code; however, restoring  the value of the `pipefail` option afterward may be required.

Comment: -1, sorry. This does not answer the question. The OP is not using a pipeline, so obviously (s)he does not need `pipefail`.

Comment: For context: This answer is based on inferring from the OP's statement that `the command behind the rm command is executed successfully` that a [command] _pipeline_ may be in the mix and thus explains how to detect failure _in a pipeline_.